# Can a Salesforce URL in a spreadsheet be opened as a Salesforce Console primary tab by default?

Tags: integration, google-apps

A team is working from a Google Sheets spreadsheet which includes SFDC URLs. The spreadsheet displays nicely in the Salesforce Console, but when a user clicks a link, the Salesforce record opens in a separate browser tab, even if the URL is in the console format (e.g., https://[my domain].my.salesforce.com/console#%2F[record ID] ).

Is there a way to force such links to open as primary tabs in the console by default?